# Google Script Autocomplete activates when semicolon is pressed instead of period

Tags: google-apps-script, autocomplete, google-apps-script-editor, azerty-keyboard

I started using Google Script a few hours ago, and I noticed that the Autocompletion doesn't not work correctly. It activates when I press ; (semicolon), but not when I press . (period).

```js
Logger.    // Does not display anything
Logger;    // Diplays clear(), getLog(), ...
```

I am using an french AZERTY keyboard and I noticed that when I switch a QUERTY keyboard, then it works correctly.

It makes everything hard to do because, first I do not have the autocomplete, and also it inserts a method at the end of the line every time I press Semicolon and Enter...

Does anyone knows why I have this problem or how to fix it ?
Thank you!

Comment: Create a issue in issuetracker. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this for documentation purposes.

This behaviour [was reported in Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36758602) a few weeks ago. Users who are experiencing this and want to keep track of this case might want to click the star on the top left in the referenced page.

#### Reference:

- [Issue Tracker: Autocompletion dialog malfunctions on AZERTY keyboards](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36758602)

Comment: I saw this issue just after I posted the question on StackOverflow ... Thank you !